# How to prove that $\neg((A\cap B)\cup (\neg A \cap C)) = (A\cap\neg B)\cup (\neg A\cap \neg C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

How can I prove the following statements are equivalent using laws of set theory?

$\neg((A\cap B)\cup (\neg A \cap C)) = (A\cap\neg B)\cup (\neg A\cap \neg C)$

I managed to use De Morgans laws to simplify the first statement down to:

$(\neg A\cup\neg B)\cap (A \cup \neg C)$ but I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: You might want to consider learning the notation to type LateX here,  it'll generally need to much better results.

Comment: Edited it thanks to some helpful users :)

Comment: What does $\neg$ mean here? $\neg$ is used in the context of Boolean algebra almost exclusively.

Comment: It's supposed to symbolize complement

Comment: @CameronWilliams In propositional logic, and my introduction set theory, $\neg$ was used always to represent complement, other than some cases where $A^C$ was used. What is used alternatively? I will edit in future with whatever is mainstream.

Comment: @Committingtoaname I've seen $A^c$ but I think people frown upon that because it could mean the set of functions from $c$ to $A$. The generally accepted notation I think is simply $X\setminus A$ where $X$ is the universe set.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Ahh yes, I have seen that in Cohn's classic algebra. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: @Committingtoaname of course! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

$\neg((A \cap B) \cup (\neg A \cap C)) = \neg(A \cap B) \cap \neg(\neg A \cap C)$ by de Morgans' law.

$= \neg(A \cap B) \cap \neg(\neg A \cap C) = (\neg A \cup \neg B) \cap (\neg\neg A \cup \neg C)$ by two applications of de Morgan again.

Now use distributivity ($D \cap (E \cup F) = (D \cap E) \cup (D \cap F)$, etc.) and $\neg\neg A = A$ to get that the latter equals:

$=((\neg A \cup \neg B) \cap A)  \cup ((\neg A \cup \neg B) \cap \neg C)$ which equals (twice distributity again):

$= (\neg A \cap A) \cup (\neg B \cap A) \cup (\neg A \cap \neg C) \cup (\neg B \cap \neg C)$, and now $A \cap \neg A = \emptyset$, and $(\neg B \cap \neg C)$ is absorbed by the other terms, after we split it using distributivity and $A \cup \neg A$ equals the whole space:

$= (A \cap \neg B) \cup (\neg A \cap \neg C) \cup (\neg B \cap \neg C) = $

$= (A \cap \neg B) \cup (\neg A \cap \neg C) \cup (\neg B \cap \neg C \cap A) \cup (\neg B \cap \neg C \cap \neg A)$

and the third term is already a subset of the first, and the fourth is a subset of the second, so we are left with

$(A \cap \neg B) \cup (\neg A \cap \neg C) $, as required.